# "Видишь что делает". Требуется ли здесь запятая и почему?

Tags: пунктуация

В справочнике по русскому языку Розенталя, 9-е издание, есть такой пример:

> А бабка Варвара, видишь что делает?

Поискав в интернете, я нашел упоминание этого же примера, но уже без запятой. Так кто же ошибается?

Answer (score 7):

Правильно: **А бабка Варвара видишь что делает? Здесь «видишь» — частица.**

[Розенталь § 25. Вводные слова и словосочетания](http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=122)

Я, **видишь**, всё это уже испытал. (**Вводное слово**). А бабка Варвара **видишь** что делает? (**Близко к частице**).
В приведенных примерах лексическое значение слов видишь, знаешь и т. п. ослаблено, поскольку они оказались внутри предложения, которое по смыслу должно было бы от них зависеть; ср.: Знаешь, что нам за это будет?; Знаете, что я нашёл в углу?; **Видишь, что** делает бабка Варвара?

Comment: а "видишь" является частью речи здесь?

Answer (score 6):

В справочнике допущена ошибка. В последующих справочниках этот пример приводится без запятой.

Обратите внимание, что в справочнике приводятся параллельные примеры с вводным словом и частицей.

> Он, знаешь, человек обязательный — вводное слово; А нам за это знаешь что будет? — близко к частице; Потом лето было знаешь какое!;

В этих примерах, если вы заметили, вводное слово отделяется запятой, а частица нет.

Поэтому и вашем примере не должно быть запятой, так как  "видишь" выступает в роли частицы.

Answer (score 4):

**А бабка Варвара видишь что делает?**
[**Вводные слова и словосочетания**](http://www.evartist.narod.ru/text1/47.htm)

Действительно, в параграф 99, п.2 вкралась ошибка, запятая не нужна:
*А бабка Варвара **видишь** что делает?* (в значении экспрессивно-усилительной частицы).

Правильные примеры можно посмотреть [**здесь**](http://lingvotech.com/vvod) и [**здесь**](http://lb2001.narod.ru/doc/statya295.htm)

`